# hacer una busqueda de un caracter en una cadena y eliminar todo despues de ese caracter

Tags: python

espero puedan ayudarme, estoy intentando hacer un programa en python donde recorra una cadena y cuando encuentre el caracter **':'** borre todo lo que sigue despues de ese caracter, mi programa es este pero al ejecutarlo solo borra el ultimo numero y se detiene el ciclo, espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias!

```
a='10.23.89.76:514'
i=0
w=len(a)

for x in reversed(a):
    while i < w:
        if x != ':':
            ip=a[:-1]
        i=i+1
print(ip)
```

el resultado que quiero obtener es: **10.23.89.76**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que efectivamente pides "todo menos el último caracter" en

```
ip=a[:-1]
```

que es una expresión *constante* (no depende de donde encuentres el ":").

El mismo algoritmo se puede simplificar simplemente recorriendo el arreglo por indices en orden inverso:

```
a='10.23.89.76:514'
for i in range(len(a)-1, -1, -1):
    if a[i] == ':':
        ip = a[:i]
        break

print(ip)
```

Una alternativa más pitonica, sin ciclos, que funciona incluso si el elemento trae varios ":":

```
a='10.23:89.76:514'
b = a.split(":")
ip = ':'.join(b[:-1])
```

Ahora, si el texto sólo trae un ":", es todavía más simple:

```
a='10.23.89.76:514'
ip, puerta = a.split(":")
```

`split(":")` genera una lista de valores que puedo descomprimir de inmediato, asignandolos a variables con nombre.

Comment: Yo, en lugar de hacer que Python recorra toda la cadena al cohete cuando nos alcanza con la primera ocurrencia, usaría el argumento maxsplit para limitarlo a la primera ocurrencia.

Comment: Con primera ocurrencia, me refiero a la primera si recorremos la cadena desde la derecha

Comment: @DanteS. El código se detiene en la primera ocurrencia desde la derecha. Así entendi que lo pedía.

Comment: Exacto. Nuestros códigos hacen lo mismo. Solo que, en mi opinión, tu respuesta le da más trabajo a Python y al programador. Aunque te pongo a favor que también te centraste en explicar como arreglar el código original.

Comment: 1) Me pongo al nivel del OP 2) Tomo su código como base para que perciba como mejorarlo 3) Le muestro como combinar funciones sencillas para llegar al mismo resultado. 4) El empeño es más didáctico que nada.

Comment: Yo hago igual, pero esta vez me comí esa parte. Pero cuando me di cuenta, fue demasiado tarde. Si ahora hiciera así, no aportaría nada que tu respuesta no haya dado. Si no eliminé mi respuesta, es por que considero que puedo proponer una alternativa.

Comment: 4) Yo trato de encontrar un equilibrio entre didactico y efectividad. Si le diera prioridad a lo didactico, motivaría malas practicas.

Answer (score 0):

Nota: Recién me doy cuenta que no expliqué el error y como mejorar el código original. Pero Candid Moe hizo ya una explicación. Así que dejaré mi respuesta como una solución alternativa.

No se si es un ejercicio de clase y por eso no usas la tecnica que mencionaré más adelante (si ese es el caso, me lo podrías aclarar por favor?). Pero lo que buscas, se puede hacer en una sola linea gracias a que Python tiene métodos de cadena muy buenos.

```
ip = a.rsplit(":", 1)[0]
```

El método rsplit separa la cadena en una lista de partes usando de separador la cadena que le pases como primer argumento, empezando a buscar el separador desde la derecha. El segundo argumento indica la cantidad maxima de veces que se separa la cadena.
Por ejemplo `print("123.456:789:1011".rsplit(":", 1))` imprimiría `["123.456:789", "1011"]`.

Teniendo esa lista, simplemente tomas el primer valor que será la ip sin lo que está después del ultimo ":".

Esta tecnica funciona bien incluso si no contiene ningún ":".

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, es parte de un programa que estoy haciendo pero me atore en esta parte, soy nueva en python, muchas gracias de nuev!! :D

Comment: De nada! Leer la documentación para conocer las cosas con las que viene Python es algo muy util. Yo conocí rsplit leyendo la documentación c: